# How can I use a for loop code in a matrix with R

Tags: r

I have got a question about for loops in R.

I want to create a matrix with the following code: (I ran it and the outcome is the right one)

```
mat <- matrix(data = c(2,0,2,7,7,3,9), nrow = 7, ncol = 16)
```

I now want to use a for loop to alter the columns 14 and 16. They currently have 2,0,2,7,7,3,9 as data. I would like to change that with a for loop to 9,9,9,9,9,9,9. How is this possible?

Thanks for helping a newbie out!

Comment: `mat[,14:16] <- 9`

Comment: @Phil you forgot to use a loop! Try `for(i in 1) {mat[,14:16] <- 9}`. (Though I think OP wants 14 and 16, but not 15, so `c(14, 16)` rather than `14:16` is a legit typo correction.)

Comment: @GregorThomas How about `for(i in 1:7) {mat[i,14:16] <- 9}`? And yes, I misread should be `mat[,c(14,16)] <- 9`

Comment: @Phil Too real!